# generated a sum report, with two different product attributes

Tags: sql

Table: orders

| orders_id | date_purchased |
| --- | --- |
| 5000 | 2021-02-01 12:27:15 |
| 5001 | 2021-02-01 11:47:15 |
| 5002 | 2021-02-02 1:47:15 |

Table: orders_products

| orders_id | products_id | orders_products_id | products_model | products_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 348 | 42169479 | APPLE | 2 |
| 5001 | 349 | 42169478 | BANANA | 1 |
| 5001 | 348 | 42169477 | APPLE | 1 |
| 5002 | 348 | 42169476 | APPLE | 3 |

Table: orders_products_attributes

| orders_products_attributes_id | orders_id | orders_products_id | products_options | products_options_values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200035 | 5000 | 42169479 | Color | Black |
| 200036 | 5000 | 42169479 | Size | XL |
| 200037 | 5001 | 42169478 | color | Green |
| 200038 | 5001 | 42169478 | Size | L |
| 200037 | 5001 | 42169477 | color | Orange |
| 200038 | 5001 | 42169477 | Size | XL |
| 200039 | 5002 | 42169476 | Color | Black |
| 200040 | 5002 | 42169476 | Size | XL |

My goal is to have a table/report that tells me how many of each size/color were ordered over a defined period of time for just 1 specific model. However I can't seem to figure out how to combine the size/color rows into the sql statement so that it doesnt make a row for each.

what I want is a table that looks like:

| products_model | color | size | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | Black | XL | 5 |
| APPLE | Orange | XL | 1 |

My best effort so far is has to ignore which color attribute is:

```
SELECT  distinct  op.products_model, sum(op.products_quantity), opa.products_options_values
FROM orders o  
LEFT JOIN orders_products op 
    ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
LEFT JOIN orders_products_attributes opa
    on op.orders_id = opa.orders_id
WHERE op.products_model in ('Apple')
and  opa.products_options_values in ('XL')
and o.date_purchased > '2020-02-02 11:47:15'
```

The issue is the above sql will ignore which color so it will show a table that says there are 6 size XL apples. but really i need to specify the color as well. I don't mind having to do different queries for each size and color but if I change the sql to something like:

```
SELECT  distinct  op.products_model, sum(op.products_quantity), opa.products_options_values
FROM orders o  
LEFT JOIN orders_products op 
    ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
LEFT JOIN orders_products_attributes opa
    on op.orders_id = opa.orders_id
WHERE op.products_model in ('Apple')
and  opa.products_options_values in ('XL')
and  opa.products_options_values in ('Black')
and o.date_purchased > '2020-02-02 11:47:15'
```

It does not work. Secondly it would be super fancy if I could generate a table that has all of the sizes and colors summed by quantity but I feel like it is not possible to do with one sql statement.

Comment: You should read about normalization and revise your schema.

Comment: Here is a fiddle link if anybody wants to save their time http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a59cf/6

Comment: @stickybit Agreed, I was thinking of using a `Pivot` until I realized there are multiple options in column `products_options_values`. Long winded to separate color and size.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be achieved by joining twice to table: `orders_products_attributes`:

```
SELECT op.products_model,
    opac.products_options_values AS color,
    opas.products_options_values AS size,
    SUM(op.products_quantity) AS quantity
FROM orders o  
JOIN orders_products op 
ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
LEFT JOIN orders_products_attributes opac
    on op.orders_products_id = opac.orders_products_id
    AND opac.products_options = 'Color'
LEFT JOIN orders_products_attributes opas
    on op.orders_products_id = opas.orders_products_id
    AND opas.products_options = 'Size'
WHERE op.products_model in ('Apple')
  AND o.date_purchased > '2020-02-02 11:47:15'
  AND opas.products_options_values = 'XL'
GROUP BY op.products_model,
         opac.products_options_values,
         opas.products_options_values;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfab127d928d4d79865802e367d5a2b7)**

Output:

```
+-----------------+---------+-------+----------+
| products_model  | color   | size  | quantity |
+-----------------+---------+-------+----------+
| APPLE           | Black   | XL    |        5 |
| APPLE           | Orange  | XL    |        1 |
+-----------------+---------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT op.products_model, sum(op.products_quantity), opa.products_options_values
FROM orders o JOIN
     orders_products op 
     ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id JOIN
     orders_products_attributes opa
     ON op.orders_id = opa.orders_id AND
        op.orders_products_id = opa.orders_products_id
WHERE op.products_model in ('Apple') AND
      opa.products_options_values in ('XL') AND
      o.date_purchased > '2020-02-02 11:47:15'
GROUP BY op.products_model, opa.products_options_values;
```

Note:  Because this is an aggregation query I added an explicit `GROUP BY`.  Also the `LEFT JOIN` is turned to an `INNER JOIN` anyway, so it is superfluous.

Comment: But does this take into consideration the color black or orange?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot to get **products_options** in columns like color, size

[image]

Rest of the work is pretty simple. All you have to do is grouping the result by  products_model,color and size to get sum(products_quantity)

Query:

```
select products_model, color, size, sum(products_quantity) Quantity    
from
    (select 
         o.products_model, o.products_quantity,    
         opa.orders_id, opa.products_options, opa.products_options_values
     from 
         Orders_products_attributes opa 
     inner join 
         Orders_Products o on o.orders_id = opa.orders_id 
                           and o.ORDERS_PRODUCT_ID = opa.ORDERS_PRODUCT_ID
     inner join 
         orders on orders.orders_id = o.orders_id
     where
         o.products_model in ('Apple')  
         and orders.date_purchased > '2020-02-02 11:47:15'
         and o.orders_id in (select orders_id 
                             from Orders_products_attributes 
                             where products_options_values = 'XL')
     ) d
pivot
    (max(products_options_values)
        for products_options in (color,size)
    ) piv
group by 
    products_model,color,size;
```

Final output:

[image]

If `products_options` column has multiple distinct value (color, size, weight etc.) and you don't know the list then you can use dynamic SQL to pivot the results dynamically with below query. Though output will be same but it will be way to slower then the first option.

Query with dynamic pivoting (much slower):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(products_options) 
            FROM Orders_products_attributes
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
        

SET @query = 'SELECT products_model, ' + @cols + ',sum(products_quantity)Quantity from 
            (
                 select o.products_model, o.products_quantity, opa.orders_id,opa.products_options,opa.products_options_values
  from Orders_products_attributes opa inner join Orders_Products o on o.orders_id=opa.orders_id AND O.ORDERS_PRODUCT_ID=OPA.ORDERS_PRODUCT_ID
  inner join orders on orders.orders_id=o.orders_id
  WHERE o.products_model in (''Apple'')  
  and orders.date_purchased > ''2020-02-02 11:47:15''
  and o.orders_id in (select orders_id from Orders_products_attributes where products_options_values=''XL'')
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(products_options_values)
                for products_options in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            group by products_model,color,size'



execute(@query);
```